# Simple stacked row chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

While I have created simple stacked row/bar charts previously by using a `let` counter as per [How to stack rects respective of previous rect's height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718937/how-to-stack-rects-respective-of-previous-rects-height), but I would like to see if it's advantageous to use the `.keys()` and `.stack()` calls like we might see in one of [Bostock's examples](https://bl.ocks.org/mjfoster83/7c9bdfd714ab2f2e39dd5c09057a55a0). Here is a simple snippet of my latest attempt:

```js
var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

var data = [
  {'country':'USA', 'value':.20},
  {'country':'Canada', 'value':.15},
  {'country':'Mexico', 'value':.10}
];

var colorMap = {
  'USA':"#f6d18b",
  'Canada':"#366092",
  'Mexico':"#95b3d7",
  "":"#a6a6a6"
};

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0,width])
    .domain([0,1]);

var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([height,0])
    .domain([0,1]);

graphGroup.append('g')
    .selectAll('g')
    .data(d3.stack().keys(colorMap)(data))
    .enter().append('g')
      .style('fill', function(d) {return colorMap[d.country]; })
    .selectAll('rect')
    .data(function(d) {return d; })
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
      .attr('x', function(d) {return xScale(d); })
      .attr('y', 40)
      .attr('width', function(d) {return xScale(d[0]) - xScale(d[1]); });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

There is no error thrown, and my implementation seems identical to Bostock's example (save for mine being a row chart, his being a bar chart). I noted that `keys()` expects an object, so I passed `colorMap` to it -- which has the correct keys.

### Question

What is going awry with my implementation of `.keys()` / `.stack()`? The result should be one stacked row of rects where the width is `value` from the data, as seen in:

```
var data = [
  {'country':'USA', 'value':.20},
  {'country':'Canada', 'value':.15},
  {'country':'Mexico', 'value':.10}
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a misconception in your question about what a `stack()` does.

First of all, your data is not ready to be passed to the stack generator. In your array each object is a single data point, only describing the country and it's value. There is nothing to be stacked there. If you look at the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/v1.3.4/README.md#_stack), you'll see:

> [...] each series i in the returned array corresponds to the ith key. Each series is an array of points, where each point j corresponds to the jth element in the input data.

You have just two properties per object, one of which is categorical, not quantitative. Therefore, you can't stack the data array you have.

On the other hand, if you had:

```
var data = [
  {year: 2016, USA: 0.20, Mexico: 0.10, Canada: 0.15},
  {year: 2016, USA: 0.40, Mexico: 0.04, Canada: 0.45},
  {year: 2016, USA: 0.07, Mexico: 0.19, Canada: 0.17},
  {year: 2016, USA: 0.11, Mexico: 0.30, Canada: 0.18}
];
```

You could do:

```js
var data = [
  {year: 2016, USA: 0.20, Mexico: 0.10, Canada: 0.15},
  {year: 2016, USA: 0.40, Mexico: 0.04, Canada: 0.45},
  {year: 2016, USA: 0.07, Mexico: 0.19, Canada: 0.17},
  {year: 2016, USA: 0.11, Mexico: 0.30, Canada: 0.18}
];
    
var stack = d3.stack().keys(["USA", "Mexico", "Canada"]);
var stackedData = stack(data);
console.log(stackedData)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Also, note that `keys` accepts a function or an array, not an object.

Comment: Ok noted. If `d3.stack()` does not lend itself to a data structure such as mine (objects of single data points), is the simplest way to create a single stacked row to use a `let` counter?

Comment: Updated with your variables, but now there are errors.

Comment: I don't know what you updated your question, I explicitly told you that you cannot stack that data structure. The `NaN`s are expected.

Comment: I updated the data to the structure you articulated on in your post: `[{USA: 0.20, Mexico: 0.10, Canada: 0.15}];` So it's not single data points anymore. Doesn't this mean that the data can be stacked now, theoretically speaking?

Comment: First, that updated data structure works: https://jsfiddle.net/0Lo6mfbp/. The `NaN`s you get now are due to a **different** problem. Also, please don't edit your question to a new code with a new data structure, that makes my answer completely unrelated and useless.