# Unable to stack rects horizontally

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am simply trying to find the easiest/most sublime way to create a single row of stacked rects. Using a `let` counter as per [How to stack rects respective of previous rect's height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55718937/how-to-stack-rects-respective-of-previous-rects-height) to store the previous data point can work or calculating all the points outright can work too as in: http://bl.ocks.org/wpoely86/e285b8e4c7b84710e463. Yet both these seem really elaborate for what seems to be a simple task: find where to put the `x` of a rect and how wide that rect should be. I went with the `let` approach below in this snippet:

```js
    var margins = {top:20, bottom:300, left:30, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
    .append('svg')
    .attr('width', totalWidth)
    .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
    .attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

 var qScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([749,0])
    .domain([0,20]);

var quartiles = [3.78, 6.69, 10.09];

let qCounter = 0;
let wCounter = 0;

graphGroup.selectAll('.markers')
    .data(quartiles)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr('class', 'markers')
    .attr('x', function(d) {
      let previous = qCounter;
      return (qCounter += qScale(d), previous)
    })
    .attr('y', 50)
    .attr('width', function(d) {return 749-qScale(d); })
    .attr('height', 50)
    .style('fill', 'gray')
    .style('stroke', '3px');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

It doesn't appear to be working correctly, there are only 2 rects. There should be 3 and they should be stacked close together. Their widths are determined by the values in `quartiles`.

### Question

Assuming my `.attr('x')` logic is right, how can I determine the right width for the rects?

I am running into the same problem because I have no means that are in scope to reference the previous data point if I wanted to trying calculating the width for the rect as the pseudocode: `qScale(d[1]) - qScale(d[0])`. Must I make another counter for each such attribute? I'm using d3 v5, is there really no easier way to find the previous datum for use with stacking rects and the like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `qScale` range is inverted, it should be:

```
.range([0, 749])
```

Even better, you should avoid magic numbers:

```
.range([0, width])
```

After doing that, change the width to just this:

```
.attr('width', function(d) {
    return qScale(d);
})
```

Here is the code with those changes, and using a colour scale to differentiate the bars:

```js
var margins = {
  top: 20,
  bottom: 300,
  left: 30,
  right: 100
};

var height = 600;
var width = 900;

var totalWidth = width + margins.left + margins.right;
var totalHeight = height + margins.top + margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width', totalWidth)
  .attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + margins.left + "," + margins.top + ")");

var colors = d3.schemeCategory10;

var qScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain([0, 20]);

var quartiles = [3.78, 6.69, 10.09];

let qCounter = 0;
let wCounter = 0;

graphGroup.selectAll('.markers')
  .data(quartiles)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', 'markers')
  .attr('x', function(d) {
    let previous = qCounter;
    return (qCounter += qScale(d), previous)
  })
  .attr('y', 50)
  .attr('width', function(d) {
    return qScale(d);
  })
  .attr('height', 50)
  .style('fill', function(_, i) {
    return colors[i]
  })
  .style('stroke', '3px');
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```